# Admin Product View Page Error on Sort Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, admin, ui-grid

I am attempting a simple task, to **sort the product filter in the admin panel** page but I am receiving the error:

> Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.

I have looked at the server logs and the following **PHP error** is being thrown up when I attempt to sort/filter in the product page of admin panel.

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: 
Method Magento\\Ui\\TemplateEngine\\Xhtml\\Result::__toString() must not 
throw an exception, 
caught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
Magento\\InventorySalesAdminUi\\Model\\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::
execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in 
/var/www/vhosts/mywebsitehere.com/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales- 
admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70 in 
/var/www/vhosts/mywebsitehere.com/vendor/magento/module- 
ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php on line 0\n'
```

This is a **clean install of Magento 2.3.0** with only my Magento 1 migrated products added. Using PHP 7.2.15, Plesk Onyx v17.8.11_build1708180301.19 os_CentOS 7.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you write detail how you generate this?

Comment: Hi @SohelRana simply go to (in admin panel) catalog > products and attempt to use any of the filtering options (e.g. in my case to sort the ID).

Comment: It sounds like something might have gone wrong in your data migration. If you look at `SaleableQuantity.php` where it calls `GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute()`  it's trying to pass `$row['sku']`, but it's passing that value as NULL. You could first try clearing all cache and generated files to see if it's an issue there. If it's not that then my guess is it's related to the migration.

Comment: All those quantities are '0' so do you think that could be it? Perhaps if I change them all to 1?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SKU should be empty or string. In your case, it is null or not a string.

Run follwoing query will resolve your issue if it is null sku related error:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL;
```

You can check your corrupted sku and fix that.

Comment: Hi @SohelRana I don't get any affected rows for that query... wondering if it's to do with the new inventory management 2.3 has?

Comment: Definitely, your SKU has some corrupted data. I created this error with default fresh installation. So check your corrupted sku that is not a string.

Comment: Or you can replace by: public function execute(?string $sku): array

Comment: Genius.. there was one product (on page 346 of 346... of course) that had no SKU value. Really appreciate the help @SohelRana

Comment: saved my life <3

Comment: Yes, sku is NULL. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Great, save my time